Combined quantifier notation
For many years I've had this notion that all kinds of expressions where you pick out a variable to vary over, the expression ought to be reducible to a single form. I'm talking about expressions like
$\forall x.\Phi(x)$
{$x : \Phi(x)$}
$\sum_{x=0}^n \Psi(x)$
$\lambda x . \Psi(x)$
where $\Phi(x)$ represents a formula containing $x$ and $\Psi(x)$ represents an expression containing $x$.
It seems like there is a common concept here, where the notation picks out a set or a sequence of values and then does something with them, so you could use one notation to pick out the set or sequence of values and then a single operator symbol to say what you are doing with them. Just curious if anyone has seen a proposal along these lines.

Yes, the common concept is that of bounded variable (vs free).  The old terminology of "apparent" variable can be useful: in a nutshell the meaning of $\forall x \varphi(x)$ is the same as $\forall y \varphi(y)$ and so on.

See Bertrand Russell, Mathematical Logic as based on the Theory of Types (American Journal of Mathematics, 1908), page 228: "If $\varphi(x)$ is a propositional function, we will denote by "$(\forall x) \varphi(x)$ " the proposition "$\varphi(x)$ is always true." This means that the variable $x$ when bound does not refer to an individual.

Giuseppe Peano around 1890 explained the introduction of the universal quantifier using the analogy with the integral notation with the variable of integration.

@MauroALLEGRANZA, I was asking for something more than a common name.

All of these are instances of map and fold.
$$\begin{matrix}\forall x \in S . \Phi(x) & \equiv & \Big(\mathtt{fold}\left[\bigwedge\right]\circ\mathtt{map}\left[\Phi\right]\Big)(S)\\
\{ x\in S : \Phi(x)\}
&\equiv&
\left(\mathtt{fold}\left[\bigcup\right]\circ\mathtt{map}\left[ x\mapsto \small{\begin{cases} \{x\} & \Phi(x)\\\varnothing & \text{else}\end{cases}} \right]\right)(S)\\
\sum_{x=0}^n Ψ(x) 
&\equiv&
\Big(\mathtt{fold}\left[\sum\right]\circ\mathtt{map}[Ψ]\Big)(\{0,1,...,n\})\\
λx.Ψ(x)&\equiv& \Big(\mathtt{fold}\left[\iota\right]\circ\mathtt{map}[Ψ]\Big)\end{matrix}$$
Of course, most of these are logically prior to map and/or fold - to even define the folding functions you'd probably have to use some sort of universal quantifier. And the last one's somewhat forced. But if you're looking for some unifying idea, this is one way to express it.
"Map" and "fold" are terms typically used in functional programming rather than math, though. For map, we call that "the image of a set $S$ through some function $f$", and often write that as $f[S]$ (though I prefer the notation $f^\to(S)$, so you can reverse the arrow for the preimage). For fold, we don't have a standard name for that in math: folding isn't as common of a procedure, since it doesn't automatically generalize to the infinite case (or even the noncommutative case). Instead, fold-flavored operators are typically just bigger versions of their binary operations: $\land$ becomes $\bigwedge$, $\oplus$ becomes $\bigoplus$, etc. (The only exception is that $+$ and $\times$ become $\sum$ and $\prod$ - blame Euler.)

How do you identify the bound variable?

@DavidGudeman I don't. The name of a bound variable is, by definition, meaningless outside of its context; it doesn't matter whether you write "$\lambda x.f(x)$" or "$\lambda \xi.f(\xi)$", both of them are just the same thing as "$f$". This notation elides them entirely (well, except for the $x$ in the second one) - it's the same thing as writing, say, $\sum S$ instead of $\sum_{x\in S} x$.

If you need to use a bound variable, you'll need lambda notation (or an equivalent, like the $x\mapsto(...)$ that I used).
